# $filter is not a function AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter, angularjs-http

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $filter) {
```

The above is an example of my code where I am trying to use `$http.get` and also `$filter` inside my `controller`.

The only problem is when I use it like so, the console log throws an error that says `$filter is not a function`.

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
```

When I swap them round it throws an error that `$http is undefined`

Comment: You have to declare `$filter` in the dependency list, i.e. `['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function($scope, $http, $filter) {...`

Comment: @NikosParaskevopoulos Sorry I forgot to add that into the example, it shows the error with this in the dependency list.

Comment: OK; there is something really fishy here. This code *should* work. Can you reproduce the problem in a fiddle/plunk?

Comment: How did you finally resolve this issue? I'm having the same problem and the answer marked below isn't working. I have the order correctly in place

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you are using

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
```

variable `$filter` is actually a instance of `$http`, and `$http` is instance of `$filter`. Actually it doesn't matter what is written in `function(...)` params.

What is important here, is the order of injectibles you are using, for example

```
app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', '$filter', function(a, b, c) {
```

will map to instances:

- a -> scope
- b -> $http
- c -> $filter

From angular docs:

> Since Angular infers the controller's dependencies from the names of arguments to the controller's constructor function, if you were to minify the JavaScript code for PhoneListCtrl controller, all of its function arguments would be minified as well, and the dependency injector would not be able to identify services correctly.

So by using array notation for yout controller, you are making sure that code will work after code is minified.

Comment: dude.. you saved me.. Thank you

Comment: while not the exact scenario, conflicting with http, I still found that changing the order fixed my issue

Answer (score 2):

add filter after http and angular version also defends how you are
    going to use filter.

```
     plateFormController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http',
    '$filter','$timeout', '$q', '$mdSidenav', '$log'];



function plateFormController($scope, $http,$filter, $timeout, $q) {
          jsonByName=$filter('filter')($scope.json, { name: 'a' });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, expected data List object is null, by ensuring that expected List Object not null. I am able to avoid this error.